# strange error messsage from jQuery .click function

Tags: jquery

I have the below code, the principle being that when clicking on the < td > it gives two alert boxes:

1)with the data-value (e.g. 1)

2) with the text (11001)

but when I click on it I get the follwoing error for the 'type' variable:

```
function ( value ) {
        return jQuery.access( this, function( value ) {
            return value === undefined ?
                jQuery.text( this ) :
                this.empty().append( ( this[0] && this[0].ownerDocument || document ).createTextNode( value ) );
        }, null, value, arguments.length );
    }
```

I'm assuming it is something quite obvious, but I can't see what???

```
<html>
<head>
    <script language="JavaScript" src="../Generic/JAVASCRIPT/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready( function() 
        {
            $('.updatefield').click(function() 
                { 
                    var typeid = $(this).closest('tr').children('td.rowType1').data('value');
                    var type = $(this).closest('tr').children('td.rowType1').text;

                    console.log(typeid);
                    console.log(type);
                }
            )
        })  
    </script>
</head>


<body>
<Table>
    <tr>
        <td class="updatefield rowType1" data-value="1">11001</td>
    </tr>
</Table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typo here:

```
var type = $(this).closest('tr').children('td.rowType1').text();
```

instead

```
var type = $(this).closest('tr').children('td.rowType1').text;
```

[.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) is method not a property.. :)

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/z4FgC/)

Answer (score 1):

`text()` is a method not a property. Thus, you're referencing rather than calling the function.

Change it to:
`var type = $(this).closest('tr').children('td.rowType1').text();`

Comment: thanks for the response, I can't believe I missed that (it was late Friday - that's my excuse). cheers.